# Adding an integer value into a database table error

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am creating a flight application in java and one of the things it is supposed to do is to add a new flight to the database. I am able to add the flight name with no issues, but I am having issues adding in the number of seats the flight has to the database. The database table is set to take in the number of seats as an integer value. In my code, my function that adds this value in from the user interface to the database takes a value as an integer argument. Then, in my event handler code for the actual button that adds a new flight, I convert the value from a string(this is what is accepted as a string from the text box) to an integer, so that the value can be entered into the database. However, when I run my code, I get an error saying the number of seats cant be accepted as a null value. Basically, the database is taking in the value as null. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code.

```
public class Flight extends Customer {
        private static ArrayList<String> FlightNames;
        private static ArrayList<Integer> Seats;
        private static PreparedStatement getFlightnames;
        private static PreparedStatement getFlightSeats;
        private static PreparedStatement addFlightName;
        private static PreparedStatement addSeats;
        private static ResultSet fresult;
        private static ResultSet sresult;

        public static ArrayList <String> getFlightnames(){
            //recieve flight names from database
            try{
                FlightNames = new ArrayList();
                getFlightnames = getConnection().prepareStatement("select name from flight ");
                fresult = getFlightnames.executeQuery();
                while(fresult.next()){
                    FlightNames.add(fresult.getString(1));

                }

            }
            catch(SQLException result){
                result.printStackTrace();
            }
            return FlightNames;

        }
        public ArrayList<Integer> getFlightSeats(){
            try{
            Seats = new ArrayList();
            //getFlightSeats = getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE Seats LIKE ?");
            getFlightSeats = getConnection().prepareStatement("select seats from flight ");
            sresult = getFlightSeats.executeQuery();
                while(sresult.next()){
                    Seats.add(sresult.getInt(1));

                }
            }

            catch(SQLException result){
                result.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Seats;
        }
        public void addFlight(String flight){
            try{
                addFlightName = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into bookings (flight) values(?)");
                addFlightName.setString(1, flight);
                addFlightName.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch(SQLException result){
                result.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void addNumber(String flightNumber){
            try{
                addFlightName = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into flight (name) values(?)");
                addFlightName.setString(1, flightNumber);
                addFlightName.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch(SQLException result){
                result.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void addSeats(int seats){
            try{
                addSeats = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into flight (seats) values(?)");
                addSeats.setInt(1, seats);
                addSeats.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch(SQLException result){
                result.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}

private void AddFlightButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        Flight addnumber = new Flight();
        Flight addseats = new Flight();
        addnumber.getConnection();
        addseats.getConnection();
        String flight = FlightTextBox.getText();
        String seats = SeatsTextBox.getText();
        int seatsInt = Integer.parseInt(seats);
        addnumber.addNumber(flight);
        addseats.addSeats(seatsInt);

        AddFlightStatusLabel.setText("The flight " + flight + " has been added with " + seats + " seats" );
        BookFlightComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(Flight.getFlightnames().toArray()));
        StatusFlightComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(Flight.getFlightnames().toArray()));
        WaitFlightComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(Flight.getFlightnames().toArray()));
    }
```

Comment: show your create table query as well

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using wrong table to add seats or wrong index for your table.

Edit:
After checking your table columns you need to add query like this for both functions but it's recommend to use only single method like this:

```
public void addFlightDetail(String flightNumber, int seats){

  addFlightName = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into flight (name, seats)
  values(?,?)");
  addFlightName.setString(1, flightNumber);
  addFlightName.setInt(1, seats);
}
```

Comment: My tables were created by hand using NetBeans. The flight name and the number of seats are in the same table. The flight name is column 1 and the number of seats is column 2. Again, the flight name is accepted as a varchar and the number of seats is accepted as an integer. When I tried to change the index to 2 for the flight seats, it gave me an error and basically said it should be 1.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. I tried to input the flight name and the number of seats as separate functions when I needed to do it as 1. That way, I can set the indexes as 1 and 2, as they should be in the table. Thanks for the input.